# I like to make the first tab open by default for tabs with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, tabs

Please help me to make the first tab open by default.
Currently, all tabs are closed. I like to make the first tab open by default.
I added a class "active" and the tab color is showing active color but the content tab is not open & showing. Any help will be appreciated!

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing is to call the function that opens the first tab after loading the page.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  if(evt) evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    else document.querySelector('button.tablinks').className += " active";
}
document.body.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', openCity(event, 'London'));
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your help.
It worked.
However, the active tab color is changed to inactive.

Comment: @PrettyStyles fix it

Answer (score 0):

Just add class `active` to the London tab.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.tabcontent.active{/* add this */
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent active">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work.

Comment: strange... i'll modify your code and works

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the selected class in the html for the first tab and remove display:none from corresponding details pane

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it didn't work.
All other tab contents are showing.

Answer (score 0):

1. It should work if you remove this line of code from the
   script:

*`document.body.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', openCity(event, 'London'));`*

2. Then add the ".active" class to the first button...
3. lastly add style="display:block; to first tab content block.

**This is my code, so I have different Id's but you can switch with yours.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->
 
<h1 align="center">Rooms</h1>
  

  
<div class="tab">
    <div class="tabs">
 <span><button class="tablinks active"  onclick="openCity(event, 'Rooms')">Rooms</button></span> 
 <span><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Cottages')">Cottages</button></span> 
 <span><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tents')">Tents</button></span> 
    </div>
</div>

  
<div>
  <div id="Rooms" class="tabcontent" style="display:block;">
   <h3>London</h3>
   <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

 <div id="Cottages" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
 </div>

 <div id="Tents" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
 </div>  
 
 </div>
  
<!-- End your code here -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

```
h1{
   color: #b4b4a2;
  font-family: lato, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }

h3{ color: #b4b4a2 ;
  
}

.tablinks{
  background-color: #a8c4c4;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: calibri, helvetica, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
}

.tabs {
  align-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  align-items: center;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  color: #a3a391;
  display: none;
  font-family: calibri, helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1.3s;
   
}

  

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    background-color: #a8c4c4;
    border: none;
  display: flex;
  
  
}
 

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0 -3px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
 
  
  }

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab .active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #a5a5a5;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #a5a5a5;
}


/* Fade in tabs */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```
//JavaScript here 

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and move the content of these comments in it. Comments are meant for discussing the answer or for feedback, they are not meant to support the answer (if they are by the author themselves).